# Change SQL Server password

Tags: sql-server

I´m trying to create a login for my SQL Server, using user/password, not Windows auth, but after I create the login and set its password, if I right-click on it and check its properties, its password is a 15-character password I don´t know.

I´ve already changed to SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode on server properties, since I saw that was a solution in another post, but I´m still having this issue. After that changed, restarted my pc in order to apply changes.

Comment: *"if I right-click on it and check its properties, its password is a 15-character password I don´t know."* What do you mean by this, you can't see the password after you create a `LOGIN`; being able to would be a **huge** security flaw if you could. Passwords for SQL Logins are hashed and salted and cannot be unhashed.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, mistaking that the box that has `` in it is saying that the password is 15 characters? It isn't, it's just a placeholder.